# Javascript display rest of the form if no checkboxes are ticked, hide if 1 or 2 of them are

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

```js
function showHide() {
  var div = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
  if (div.style.display == 'none') {
    div.style.display = '';
  } else {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="installer" onsubmit="showHide(); return false;">

  <label>Home Keyword</label>
  <br />Are you looking to live here?
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <br />Are you looking to rent?
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <br />

  <input type="submit" value="Continue" name="submit" onsubmit="showHide()">

</form>

<div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
  <p>Show rest of the form here when the above form is submitted with no checkboxes ticked</p>
</div>


<div id="sorry_div" style="display:none">
  <p>Sorry, we can't continue with your application.</p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the rest of my form to display if both of the checkboxes have remained empty (following the submit/continue button). However, at the moment it shows regardless of how many are ticked.

Following this, If both are ticked how would I go about a message coming up saying: Sorry, we can't continue or similar?

Is this relatively easy to make or quite complicated?

## **I have the following HTML:**

```
<form method="post" name="installer" onsubmit="showHide(); return false;">

    <label>Home Keyword</label>
    <br />

    Are you looking to live here? <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"><br />
    Are you looking to rent?    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Continue" name="submit" onsubmit="showHide()">

</form>

<div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
    <p>Show rest of the form here when the above form is submitted with no checkboxes ticked </p>
</div>


<div id="sorry_div" style="display:none">
    <p>Sorry, we can't continue with your application.</p>
</div>
```

**The JS:**

```
function showHide() {
    var div = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
    if (div.style.display == 'none') {
        div.style.display = '';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use an id more than once; that's a bad practice. secondly, use the `.checked` property to get the checked state of a `checkbox`, then use the logical AND operator (`&&`); to check if both the first and the second checkboxes are not checked.

**edit**: updated code to include `#sorry_div`.

```js
function showHide() {
    var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
    var sorryDiv = document.getElementById("sorry_div");
    var firstCheckBox = document.getElementById("first-checkbox").checked;
    var secondCheckBox = document.getElementById("second-checkbox").checked;
    if (firstCheckBox != 1 && secondCheckBox != 1) {
        hiddenDiv.style.display = '';
        sorryDiv.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        hiddenDiv.style.display = 'none';
        sorryDiv.style.display = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="installer" onsubmit="showHide(); return false;">

    <label>Home Keyword</label>
    <br />Are you looking to live here?
    <input id="first-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <br />Are you looking to rent?
    <input id="second-checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Continue" name="submit" onsubmit="showHide()">

</form>

<div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
    <p>Show rest of the form here when the above form is submitted with no checkboxes ticked</p>
</div>


<div id="sorry_div" style="display:none">
    <p>Sorry, we can't continue with your application.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I go about making the "sorry_div" show when they select 1 or both text boxes?

Comment: Thank you very much indeed!